# Integrability of logarithm of a function in Hardy class

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that f is in $H^1$ (The Hardy space of holomorphic functions in the unit disk). I need an easy reference to the following fact $ \log |f|$  is in $h^1$, i.e. it belongs to harmonic Hardy space.

Comment: $\log |f|$ is not harmonic when $f$ has zeros.

Comment: It is a standard fact that $\log |f|$ is integrable on any $|z|=r\le1$ when $f$ is just in Nevalinna class and is of course not identically zero (so $f$ is a ratio of bounded analytic functions on the unit disc, hence it has ae nontangential  boundary limit etc); any book on Hardy spaces like say Duren has this early as an application of Jensen and Fatou; as noted above though $\log |f|$ is in general just subharmonic unless $f$ has no zeroes in the unit disc